# Using of "with whom" in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'd like to know if the following sentence is correct in German:

> Er fand endlich eine Frau, mit der den Rest seines Lebens zu verbringen.

(He finally found a woman with whom to spend the rest of his life.)

Can you say that or is that incorrect?
Otherwise how would you say it?

Comment: "mit der er den Rest seines Lebens zu verbringen _gedachte_ / _beabsichtigte_"

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong by the following reasons:

**Either** you should fix three things:

---

1. You are missing a modal verb (e.g. *können, wollen,...*)

   > Er fand endlich eine Frau, mit der den Rest seines Lebens zu verbringen `modal verb`. (still incorrect)
2. And you are also missing a subject

   > Er fand endlich eine Frau, mit der `subject` den Rest seines Lebens zu verbringen `modal verb`.  (still incorrect)
3. Moreover, *zu* is doing nothing (so, if you correct 1. and 2., you should leave *zu* aside).

   > > Er fand endlich eine Frau, mit der `subject` den Rest seines Lebens <strike>zu</strike> verbringen `modal verb`. (Correct, if you complete correctly.)

---

**Or** the next option, which would sound funny, though:

---

1'. You are missing an *um*, and in that case *ihr* instead of *der* sounds better.

Comment: I don't think you should say "Er fand eine Frau, *um* mit ihr den Rest des Lebens zu verbringen" - This has a wrong causal relationship in my understanding ("He found a woman *because* he'd be spending his...") - *Der weiterführende Infinitiv mit um ist nicht mehr sehr gebräuchlich*.  I'd say "Er fand eine Frau, mit der er den Rest seines Lebens verbringen wollte/würde".

Comment: @tofro Fair enough. Then your suggestion is included in the first possibility, isn't it? (Übrigens finde ich diese Frage grenzwertig *proofreading*, weswegen ich keine vollständige Lösungen aufschreibe, sondern nur das, was wohl einem Menschen, der wirklich Deutsch lernt, helfen würde.)

Comment: right - You had mentioned that, and I think that sounds much better.

Comment: Note that it is one of the defining characteristics of a modal verb that it is used with a “naked” infinitive, i.e. without _zu_; so a pattern like “… zu verbringen _modal verb_” is at least misleading.

Comment: I did; that’s why I said misleading, not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to translate the English sentence "He finally found a woman with whom to spend the rest of his life." a free but good answer is "Er fand endlich die Frau für's Leben.".
2. If you want to make your German sentence "Er fand endlich eine Frau, mit der den Rest seines Lebens zu verbringen." grammatically correct, there are, besides tofros answer, several possibilities (though I absolutely wouldn't agree on "Der weiterführende Infinitiv mit um ist nicht mehr sehr gebräuchlich."):

> Er fand endlich eine Frau, mit der ER den Rest seines Lebens verbringen konnte.
>   Er fand endlich eine Frau, mit der ER den Rest seines Lebens verbringen können würde.

The "with whom + infinitive" construction cannot be translated word by word.

Answer (score -1):

Er fand endlich eine Frau, mit der er den Rest seines Lebens zu verbringen vermochte.